# Calling MySQL procedure sometimes results in Exception "Incorrect integer value: '@com_mysql_jdbc_outparam_11' for column '_NewID' at row 1"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm sporadically facing a strange exception while calling a Stored Procedure in MySQL from Java JDBC driver.
My application code looks like:

```
int newID = 0;
if (myObj != null) 
   newID = myObj.getId(); //getId() returns an int value...
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL MySP(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");          
stmt.registerOutParameter(14, Types.INTEGER);
stmt.registerOutParameter(15, Types.BIT);

stmt.setShort(1, status);
... // other setters for each parameter of the stored procedure
stmt.setInt(14, newID);

stmt.execute();

newID = stmt.getInt(14);    
createdNew = stmt.getBoolean(15);
```

Executing the statement results in a success in 99% of the cases, except few times when an Exception is raised:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '@com_mysql_jdbc_outparam_13' for column '_NewID' at row 1
```

EDIT:
This is the body of the stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddPhysNode`(
    IN _a SMALLINT,IN _b BIGINT,IN _c BIT,IN _d VARCHAR(255),IN _e LONGBLOB,IN _f LONGBLOB,IN _g INT,IN _h SMALLINT,IN _i SMALLINT,IN _l SMALLINT,
    IN _m BIT,IN _n INT,IN _o BIGINT,INOUT _NewID INT,OUT _CreatedNew BIT
)
BEGIN       
IF (_NewID > 0) THEN
    UPDATE  tbl 
    SET     a = _a
    WHERE   Id = _NewID;

    SET _CreatedNew = 0;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO tbl (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`,`l`,`m`,`n`,`o`)
    VALUES (_a,_b,_c,_d,_e,_f,_g,_h,_i,_l,_m,_n,_o);

    SET _CreatedNew = 1;
    SET _NewID = @@IDENTITY;
END IF;
END$$
```

Any hint about this?

Thank you very much!

Best

cghersi

Comment: Do you have any idea what integer raised the exception?

Comment: @Jakob it should be the "newID" variable... (com_mysql_jdbc_outparam_13 seems related to the 14th parameter)

Comment: Yes but I mean what the value was. You say it works most of the times but not always. So what value did newID have when it did not work?

Comment: That's exactly the point: it seems that Java code passed the value "@com_mysql_jdbc_outparam_13" to the stored procedure for the parameter named _NewID, which is an INTEGER. But I cannot figure out how it should be possible, given that the statement 14th parameter is filled using stmt.setInt(14, newID); instruction, where newID variable is an int. This is why I'm so puzzled.

Comment: yes I understand that, but what value SHOULD it be?

Comment: In normal condition, the value should be an integer from 0 to 100

Comment: Could you post the procedure code aswell?

Comment: delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddPhysNode`(
    IN _a SMALLINT,IN _b BIGINT,IN _c BIT,IN _d VARCHAR(255),IN _e LONGBLOB,IN _f LONGBLOB,IN _g INT,IN _h SMALLINT,IN _i SMALLINT,IN _l SMALLINT,
    IN _m BIT,IN _n INT,IN _o BIGINT,INOUT _NewID INT,OUT _CreatedNew BIT
)
BEGIN       
 IF (_NewID > 0) THEN
  UPDATE  tbl 
  SET     a = _a
  WHERE   Id = _NewID;
  
  SET _CreatedNew = 0;
 ELSE
  INSERT INTO tbl (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`,`l`,`m`,`n`,`o`)
  VALUES (_a,_b,_c,_d,_e,_f,_g,_h,_i,_l,_m,_n,_o);
   
  SET _CreatedNew = 1;
  SET _NewID = @@IDENTITY;
 END IF;
END$$

Comment: Cant find anything strange with the procedure. One idea could be to check that newId actually is an int before calling the prodecure but I dont know. One would think that the setInt(..) method should complain. One thing hat buggs me is that it says "...outparam_13" and column _NewID when the _NewID parameter should be outparam_14 and _NewID is not a column as far as I can see. Could the error be with one of the other parameters?

Comment: I see now that the error seems to say "outparam_11" in the header of this post further suggesting that there is something fishy going on with the other parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be related to a concurrency problem, in a multi-thread environment, the use of a shared prepared statement caused the execution of such statement while another thread  was assigning new values to the parameters of that statements.